# Creating a vector that holds two different data types or classes

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism

I am trying to create a vector that holds an int and a string. Is this possible?

For example I want `vector<int>myArr` to hold `string x= "Picture This"`

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating an array which can hold objects of different classes in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764671/creating-an-array-which-can-hold-objects-of-different-classes-in-c)

Comment: Wait, do you want it to hold both of them or either an int or a string in each element?

Comment: Why do you want a vector that holds an int and a string?

Answer (score 20):

You can use a union, but there are better alternatives.

You can use [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html) to get this kind of functionality:

```
using string_int = boost::variant<std::string, int>;

std::vector<string_int> vec;
```

To get either a string or an int out of a variant, you can use [`boost::get`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/get_idp132758640.html):

```
std::string& my_string = boost::get<std::string>(vec[0]);
```

**Edit**
Well, it's 2017 now. You no longer need Boost to have `variant`, as we now have [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)!

Comment: You can create a `vector` of `union` type with a fixed size string (`const char[]`) and an integer without needing to use boost. You can also use `std::string` but you need place the `union` in a `struct` with a type tag for the destructor to choose the correct type to destroy. See the end of the link in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, no need the `const` for the `char[]`.

Comment: @Magtheridon6 Regardless of those reasons, the answer to OP's question should be yes.

Comment: std::variant is available in STL starting from C++17

Comment: @AndreyStarodubtsev Good catch!

Answer (score 13):

Yes it is possible to hold two different types, you can create a `vector` of `union` types. The space used will be the larger of the types. Union types are explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) along with how you can tag the type. A small example:

```
union Numeric
{
    int i;
    float f;
};

std::vector<Numeric> someNumbers;
Numeric n;
n.i = 4;
someNumbers.push_back(n);
```

You can also use `std::string` but you need place the `union` in a `struct` with a type tag for the destructor to choose the correct type to destroy. See the end of the link.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the vector to hold two different types you can use a `std::pair` (or `std::tuple` if more than two)

In C++03:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string> > myArr;
```

If you want the vector to hold one type that can be used as two different types: No, it can't be done.

Answer (score 3):

No, a `vector` must only hold variables of the type declared within the angle brackets `<` `>`.

You could create a class that has an `int` member and a `string` member, and then create a `vector` to hold instances of that class, and then reference the `int` or `string` members when you need to.

Comment: @chris Well, that would depend on the application.

Comment: @CoryKlein: Indeed. But the advice for learners should never mention pointers in containers. It's so rarely needed, and so easily to mess up, that no purpose is served by explaining the possibility until the actual problem at hand requires it. And then you'd still suggest smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

No. `myArr` is instantiated to hold `int` type. It can store only `int` type.