# c++11 Create object instance iterated through vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a vector list with "registered" classes.

**main.cpp**

```
// main.cpp:
// from namespace::class3
bool successfulregistered = RegisterComponents(vector<CustomNamespace::class1,CustomNamespace::class2>);
```

**class3.h**

```
// in class3
    private:
        vector<CustomNamespace> Objectinstance;

    public:
        bool RegisterComponents(vector<CustomNamespace>& RegisterComponents);
```

**class3.cpp**

```
        // implementation
        bool class3::RegisterComponents(vector<CustomNamespace>& RegisterComponents)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < RegisterComponents.end(); i++)
            {
                class3::Objectinstance->iterator(*RegisterComponents);
                // and then some checks
            }
        }
```

Now I like to gather access to the classes and created object instances to call methods:

```
void class3::startserver(void)
{
    for(auto i = Objectinstance.begin(); i != Objectinstance.end(); i++)
    {
        /*  How can I create the objects from the vector list with
                their classes and call the specific constructor? */

        /* i == CustomNamespace::class1 */


    }
}
```

**class1.h**

```
ConfigWatchdog(string &SetJSONFile, const char &cJSONRoot);
```

**class2.h**

```
ServerNetworking(unit& setIPAddress, ...);
```

Comment: The question is unclear and the code does not look like compilable C++ (it confuses iterators and indices, uses `namespace` as type name, etc.) Please clarify your question and tighten up the code to help us answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Despite your code giving me a WTF moment, I think I can help. `i` in the loop is an iterator:

```
for(auto i = Objectinstance.begin(); i != Objectinstance.end(); i++)
```

You access an element by dereferencing `i` - `*i`. You can copy-construct another `Namespace` (make it capital `N`, `namespace` is a keyword, don't you know?):

```
Namespace obj1 = *i;
```

And maybe just [grab a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: But in the list are two difference classes, how can I make a difference?
vector<namespace::class1,namepsace::class2>; so while I'm iterating with i, it has in each continuity another class, which I just like to call.

Comment: `std::vector` can have elements only of one type... The second template parameter is a custom allocator. [Read the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: I edited a bit my example to make it more clear with my namespace. Sorry for confusing. :)
So `std::vector< mynamespace >Listwithmycustomclasses` may be a list with one type of elements, or not?

Comment: Wuhu ok that's already good to know. But now it's still unclear how I can access each class inside and call it with an iterator. Could you please edit your example to make it clear to me?

Comment: You have to edit your question first - I don't know what `Namespace` class looks like.

Comment: I added the constructors from my two classes. Does it help you to understand? They are also in `CustomNamespace`

Comment: Not really. Is `Namespace` even a class? Are those two classes nested inside it?

Comment: Yes they are both nested in the namespace! `Namespace` is not a class. It's a namespace which I use for my classes. They shall be saved in vector, which I like to iterate through and call the classes then.

Comment: Well, you can't have `std::vector<mynamespace>` then. You'll need one `std::vector<ConfigWatchdog>` and one `std::vector<ServerNetworking>`. It's totally unclear what you want to do... rethink your problem.

Comment: So does it not even work if `ConfigWatchdog` and `ServerNetworking`are in same `namespace`? I just want to save classes with same namespace in a list. And iterate through the list later, and create an object by each class which I have saved in the list. :( This is not possible?

Comment: `ConfigWatchdog` is totally different from `ServerNetworking`, you really better read some books.

Comment: Yes it's clear they are different, cuz they are different classes as I wrote. My question wasn't about to save **same** classes, it was all time about different classes. Else I wouldn't have this problem, right?;)
`vector<MyNamespace>Alistwithdifferentclasses`
So is it possible and if yes how and if no, why?

Comment: There already questions about that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734042/creating-a-vector-that-holds-two-different-data-types-or-classes.