# Having difficulty in creating a templatized generic vector which can hold any datatype

Tags: c++, c++14

As the topic suggests, I am trying to create a vector of which can hold any datatype. I am trying to use templates so that code can be more maintainable for future.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#include<vector>

struct prime{
    public:
        template<typename T>
        T  get();
};

template<typename T>
struct foo: prime{
    public:
        T i;
        foo(T k):i(k){
        }
        template<typename T1>
        T1 get(){
            return i;
        }

};

/*
struct fooString :prime{
    public:
        std::string i;
        fooString(std::string k):i(k){
        }
};
*/
int main(){
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<prime>> v;
    std::shared_ptr<foo<int>> p1 = std::make_shared<foo<int>>(0);
    std::shared_ptr<foo<char>> p3 = std::make_shared<foo<char>>('H'); 
    //std::shared_ptr<fooString> p2 = std::make_shared<fooString>("HK");
    v.push_back(p1);
    v.push_back(p3);
    //v.push_back(p2);
    //std::cout<<v[0]->i<<" "<<v[1]->i<<std::endl;
    //std::cout<<static_cast<foo<int>>(*v[0]).get();
    std::cout<<v[0]->get<int>();
}
```

The commented code is my different approaches I am trying to solve this issue. But I am not able to crack this. Any suggestions would help me a lot. I tried following [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734042/creating-a-vector-that-holds-two-different-data-types-or-classes) but as I said, creating union of different datatypes is difficult to maintain. And also  `boost::variant` doesn't help either as I have to give all the types it needs to hold before hand. I don't want that restriction. Can Anyone suggest me whether it is possible or I am just trying to achieve the impossible? 
I have another algorithm in my mind which is like cast everything to string and store it. But that approach doesn't look proper.

Thank you :)

Comment: So, why are you reinventing the wheel?  See `std::vector`.  It's already templatized and tested.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That's what I thought at first glance, but I think OP's problem is getting different types into one `std::vector`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews OP is already using `std::vector`, OP just wants it to hold different data types.

Comment: And that's what I thought at second glance, but Third glance looks like OP has different data types in the vector thanks to inheritance, but is really struggling with calling a function known by the subclass and not the base class.

Comment: @user4581301 sorry. I mean more maintainable or it requires less maintenance . I will edit it

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  I am trying to create a single vector which can hold different datatypes. Something like a python list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to have a container that can store *any* type, but not actually give you any information about it - it's up to you to just know which type each element is actually storing, then that's precisely what [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) (based on [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any.html)) is for.

The usage in your case would be:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<std::any> v;
    v.push_back(0);                  // an int
    v.push_back('H');                // a char
    v.push_back(std::string{"HK"});  // a string

    std::cout << std::any_cast<int>(v[0]); // this will throw if v[0] is not an int

    std::string* p = std::any_cast<std::string>(&v[1]); // this will return nullptr
                                                        // if v[1] is not a string, which
                                                        // it is not
}
```

Comment: Oh... cool.. I was looking at boost::any few minutes ago. Is there a way to store datatypes only in a container or list, somewhere? I know I can create a switch statement based on typeid from <traits> But if I can store just data type it would be great. Combination of this and your answer can lead to dataframe creation in c++ .

Comment: @srinath29 No idea what you're asking.

Comment: I am just thinking of another idea. If we can create a vector of void data type and later cast it to required data type, will it work. Your Idea is c++17. So I am just looking if I can solve it in c++14 standard. I am still touching waters of c++17. So I am being little careful

Comment: @srinath29 You can't have `vector<void>`. Also you can use `boost::any` just fine in C++14.

Comment: Now to get back to normal form from `std::any` I need to know the data type. My use case is I am storing large number "std::any " vectors in another vector. Now, if I can somehow store the datatype each "std::any" vector, then when required I can cast them accordingly for future operations. Is there any way to do that ?