# How to add and read elements of vector of two type of variables

Tags: c++, qt, vector

I read this post: [vector hold two differents data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734042/creating-a-vector-that-holds-two-different-data-types-or-classes)

Then I am trying to use this format.

I see in this post two ways to do that:

In my case:

A) `std::vector<std::pair<Vecplane3d, CartesianPoint>> vector_super;`

B) `std::vector<std::tuple<Vecplane3d, CartesianPoint>> vector_super;`

But when I want to fill this vector. I am not able to do it.

I coded this:

```
vector_centroids.push_back(vec_normal, vec_centroid);
```

And I coded other way:

```
vector_centroids.insert(vec_normal, vec_centroid);
```

Sorry but I am looking for documentatio about that and I didn't find anything.

Comment: With C++11, use `.push_back({vec_normal, vec_centroid})`. With C++03 use `std::make_pair()` explicitly, and push_back *that*.

Comment: maybe `vector_centroids.push_back(std::make_tuple(vec_normal, vec_centroid));` (when using tuple)

Comment: You could have, with a small amount of experimentation, solved or be close to solving your issue by first declaring the type you want to push into the vector, and then pushing that: `std::pair<Vecplaned3d,CartesianPoint>  myPair(vec_normal, vec_centroid); vector_centroids.push_back(myPair);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are manipulating a vector of pair/tuple, even if it aggregates two values, it's still one single element for your std::vector. That's why you have to give your vector a pair or a tuple containing your two aggregated objects:

```
vector_centroids.push_back({vec_normal, vec_centroid}); //pair
```

if you are using a tuple do:

```
vector_centroids.push_back(std::make_tuple(vec_normal, vec_centroid)); //tuple
```

Comment: Thanks, I test both and it works find. On the other hand I see that it save data like: first and second in first case.    What is the best way to access to them? and how to change label first to plane3d and second to centroid?

Comment: On second case, I am interesting too to know how to acces to content when you have a tuple.

Comment: @Iván `std::get<0>(my_tuple)`, `std::get<1>(my_tuple)`, `std::get<2>(my_tuple)`, ... see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to use a struct like the following:

```
struct NormalCentroidStruct
{
  Vecplane3d normal;
  CartesianPoint centroid;
};
```

Then, when using your vector, you could do as follows:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<NormalCentroidStruct> vector_centroids;
  //Fill vec_normal and vec_centroid
  vector_centroids.push_back({vec_normal, vec_centroid});
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's probably what OP should do, even if he asked for a solution with pair or tuple

Comment: I wasn't sure if the OP was looking to ONLY use pairs/tuples, so I figured I'd give a simple alternative in case it worked for his use case.